# How to show find replace dialog in SourceViewer(On Shortcut Ctrl+F)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using sourceViewer in a View, I have define command org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace and create a handler for the command to invoke FindReplace action.

I also define key bind to invoke the command(Ctrl+F)

Now i have override getAdapter method in View class, and added a check if the class equals org.eclipse.jface.text.IFindReplaceTarget then return textViewer.getFindReplaceTarget().

But nothing is working for me, neither on key shortcut (Ctrl+F), command is invoking nor check written for IFindReplaceTarget in getAdapter method is executing.

Can anyone please help me what went wrong or how to implement find replace functionality in SourceViewer?

Comment: If this is a plugin for Eclipse or an RCP extending Eclipse then the command `org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace` will already be defined as will the key binding Ctrl+F (in the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin).

Comment: This is rcp product, and i have checked but on Ctrl+F find dialog is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything in the Eclipse source that uses a Handler for this, rather they all use the older style actions. This is what `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.display.DisplayView` does:

```
FindReplaceAction findReplaceAction = new FindReplaceAction(bundle, "find_replace_action_", this); 
findReplaceAction.setActionDefinitionId(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_FIND_AND_REPLACE);
setGlobalAction(ActionFactory.FIND.getId(), findReplaceAction);

protected void setGlobalAction(String actionID, IAction action) {
    IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(actionID, action);
}
```